# How to profile sqlcipher on Android?

Tags: android, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

SqlCipher has profiler. 
According [documentation](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/#cipher_profile) To turn it on developer should execute:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA cipher_profile='sqlcipher.log';
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t1(a,b);
sqlite> INSERT INTO t1(a,b) VALUES('one for the money', 'two for the show');
sqlite> PRAGMA cipher_profile=off;
```

On Android I added to database hook following query
`database.rawExecSQL(“PRAGMA cipher_profile=’” + name + “.log’;”);` where name is the string path to log file. 
But I don't see any logs created with this path.

Could someone explain is it possible to profile sqlcipher on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official answer:

https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/pragma-cipher-profile-on-android/3766

> It appears there is an issue with capturing the profile output to a file on the Android platform. In the interim, you can set cipher_profile to use stdout, then redirect stdout to logcat for your emulator or rooted device.